# Как избавиться от глобальной переменной PyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Дело в том что когда кто-то смотрит фото в боте и приходит другой юзер и нажимает на другую кнопку то переменная меняется для всех и потом выводит данные для всех 2-го юзера.
Понимаю что дело в переменной `nnn` но не понимаю как по другому реализовать

```
modely_markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
for i in row:
    modely_markup.add(
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(
            text=f'(#{i[0]}) •{i[1]}• {i[-1]}', 
            callback_data="girl:"+f'{i[0]}'))
```

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
def call_back(call):
    for i in row:
        if call.data != "girl:" + f'{i[0]}': 
            continue

        #bot.send_media_group(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, media=[photo])
        bot.send_photo(
            chat_id=call.message.chat.id,
            photo=(i[2] ),
            caption=girl_Profile.format(i[1], i[-4], i[-3], i[-2]),
            reply_markup=girl_markup)

        global nnn
        caldata = call.data
        num = re.findall(r'[1-9][1-9]?',caldata)
        nnn = int(num[0])-1

    if call.data == 'next_photo':
        bot.send_media_group(
            chat_id=call.message.chat.id,
            media=([types.InputMediaPhoto(row[nnn][3]),
                   types.InputMediaPhoto(row[nnn][4]),
                   types.InputMediaPhoto(row[nnn][5])]))
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать словарь с юзерами и в них хранить нужные данные

```
from typing import Union

# делаем глобальный словарь с юзерами
data_storage: dict[int, dict[int, dict]] = {}


# функция добавления для удобства
def add_user(chat_id: int, user_id: int) -> None:
    # создаем в словаре по чайт айди пустой словарь
    data_storage.setdefault(chat_id, {})
    # в который потом пихаем юзер айди в котором будет data и state
    data_storage[chat_id].setdefault(user_id, {"data": {}, "state": ""})
    # PS если такой ключ в data_storage уже есть то он не будет перезаписывать данные


# делаем функцию для записи данных в дату
# обязательно указывать название аргумента типа update_data(message=message, data={'key':value})
def update_data(*, data: dict, user_id: int = None, chat_id: int = None,
                message: Union[types.Message, types.CallbackQuery] = None) -> None:
    if message and (chat_id or user_id):
        logging.error("В качестве аргументов использовать либо 'message' либо 'chat_id' и 'user_id'")
        return

    _user_id = message.from_user.id if message else user_id
    if isinstance(message, types.CallbackQuery):
        message = message.message
    _chat_id = message.chat.id if message else chat_id or user_id
    # на всякий случай проверяем есть ли юзер в словаре
    add_user(_chat_id, _user_id)
    # и спокойно добавляем данные в дату
    data_storage[_chat_id][_user_id]['data'].update(data)


# по аналогии с функцией выше
def get_data(*, user_id: int = None, chat_id: int = None,
             message: Union[types.Message, types.CallbackQuery] = None) -> dict:
    if message and (chat_id or user_id):
        logging.error("В качестве аргументов использовать либо 'message' либо 'chat_id' и 'user_id'")
        return {}
    _user_id = message.from_user.id if message else user_id
    if isinstance(message, types.CallbackQuery):
        message = message.message
    _chat_id = message.chat.id if message else chat_id or user_id
    add_user(_chat_id, _user_id)
    return data_storage[_chat_id][_user_id]['data']
```

Пример использования

```
@bot.message_handler()
def start(msg: types.Message):
    update_data(data={'s': '123'}, message=msg)
    data = get_data(msg) # < {'s': '123'}
```

PS. В целом `update_data` можно упростить и оставить только `message` но вдруг ты захочешь поменять данные для другого юзера и чата. Так что на ваше усмотрение.
UPD. Пример для вашего кода

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def call_back(call):
    for i in row:
        if call.data != "girl:" + f'{i[0]}':
            continue

        # bot.send_media_group(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, media=[photo])
        bot.send_photo(
            chat_id=call.message.chat.id,
            photo=(i[2]),
            caption=girl_Profile.format(i[1], i[-4], i[-3], i[-2]),
            reply_markup=girl_markup)

        caldata = call.data
        num = re.findall(r'[1-9][1-9]?', caldata)
        update_data(data={'nnn': int(num[0]) - 1}, message=call)
        # nnn = int(num[0])-1

    if call.data == 'next_photo':
        nnn = get_data(message=call).get("nnn")
        bot.send_media_group(
            chat_id=call.message.chat.id,
            media=([types.InputMediaPhoto(row[nnn][3]),
                    types.InputMediaPhoto(row[nnn][4]),
                    types.InputMediaPhoto(row[nnn][5])]))
```

Comment: Как подставить под мой код?
@oleksandrigo
переменная row это База Данных

Comment: @Yang_py обновил

Comment: AttributeError: 'CallbackQuery' object has no attribute 'chat'
@oleksandrigo
ошибка

Comment: @Yang_py вроде исправил