# PyTelgramBotAPI: кнопка срабатывает сама по себе

Tags: python, telebot

Кнопка "next_photo" сама по себе срабатывает, когда выполняется условия 1. Как это исправить?

```python
modely_markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
for i in row:
    modely_markup.add(
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=f'(#{i[0]}) •{i[1]}• {i[-1]}', callback_data="girl:"+f'{i[0]}'))


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
def call_back(call, ):
    for i in row:
        if call.data != "girl:" + f'{i[0]}':
            continue
 
        bot.send_photo(chat_id=call.message.chat.id,
                       photo=(i[2] ),
                       caption=girl_Profile.format(i[1], i[-4], i[-3], i[-2]),
                       reply_markup=girl_markup
                       )

        if call.data != 'next_photo':    # Когда стоит ==, оно вообще не реагирует
            bot.send_media_group(chat_id=call.message.chat.id,
                                 media=([types.InputMediaPhoto(i[3]),
                                        types.InputMediaPhoto(i[4]),
                                        types.InputMediaPhoto(i[5])]
                             ))
```

Comment: только что просмотрел что получает call.data оно показывает значение 1 call.data

Comment: Вероятно, это индекс нажатой кнопки.

Comment: @Vestalt так там на второй иф приходит каллдата та же что и на первый, вот и она срабатывает потому что оно неравно этому тексту, тогда вопрос как получить значение для второго ифа

Comment: @oleksandrigo вот тут была сама причина а не в этом [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1475861/Как-избавиться-от-глобальной-переменной-pytelegrambotapi/1475950?noredirect=1#comment2644413_1475950]